# How to not show the content of execution of contentreplace from a pipeline jenkins

Tags: jenkins, plugins, passwords, jenkins-pipeline

I'm looking to inject password from an application Vault in a properties file during a pipeline jenkins. I've found a solution which works. But i'm not very happy with this solution.

The password is not hidden. ***I can read the password in the log job*** of the pipeline Jenkins. This log is due to the contentreplace plugin .

Have someone idea to secure this behavior?

Here an example of log generate by contentreplace plugin in my log job:

```
00:46:17 replace file content: /tmp/workspace/EXAMPLE_JOB_CONTENTREPLACE/application.properties
00:46:17  replace times: 0, [\{\{FTP_PASSWD\}\}] => [thisismyftppwd]
```

An example of what i'm doing, i have suppressed the Vault code to simplify the demonstration.

```
stage ('Inject Secrets') {
    steps {
        script {
            node {

                def vaultData = [:]
                vaultData['ftp_password'] = 'thisismyftppwd'
                contentReplace(
                    configs: [ fileContentReplaceConfig( 
                        configs: [ fileContentReplaceItemConfig(
                            search: '\\{\\{FTP_PASSWD\\}\\}', replace: vaultData['ftp_password'])],
                        fileEncoding: 'UTF-8', filePath:
                            " ${WORKSPACE}/application.properties")])

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MaskPasswordsBuildWrapper` of [wrap: General Build Wrapper](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#wrap-general-build-wrapper) as following:

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {
    stage('Build') {
      steps {
        script {
          sh "touch ${WORKSPACE}/application.properties"
          sh "echo '{{FTP_PASSWD}}' > ${WORKSPACE}/application.properties"

          def vaultData = [ftp_password:'thisismyftppwd']
          def ftp_password = vaultData['ftp_password']

          wrap([
            $class: 'MaskPasswordsBuildWrapper', 
            varPasswordPairs: [
              [password: ftp_password, var: 'ftp_password']
            ]
          ]) {
              echo "${ftp_password}"

              contentReplace(
                configs: [ 
                  fileContentReplaceConfig( 
                    configs: [ 
                      fileContentReplaceItemConfig(
                        search: '\\{\\{FTP_PASSWD\\}\\}', 
                        replace: "${ftp_password}"
                      )
                    ],
                    fileEncoding: 'UTF-8', 
                    filePath: "${WORKSPACE}/application.properties"
                  )
                ]
              )
          }

          echo '########'
          sh "cat ${WORKSPACE}/application.properties"

        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is what i'm looking! I have changed your solution. You have to declare var ftp_password before calling varPasswordPairs. I also change sh command to have a solution ready to debug. :)